# Add fields and values based on conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to add fields and values based on conditions on an existing index.
Context: 1 000 000 "rows" and one index.

What could be the most efficient way to do this:

```
If field_a = 1 and (field_b > 0 or field_c > 0 or field_d > 0)
    then
        add new field field_e with value = 1 
    else
        add new field field_e with value = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely achievable using the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html):

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"exists": {"field": "field_a"}},
        {"exists": {"field": "field_b"}},
        {"exists": {"field": "field_c"}},
        {"exists": {"field": "field_d"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.field_e = (ctx._source.field_a == 1 && (ctx._source.field_b > 0 || ctx._source.field_c > 0 || ctx._source.field_d > 0)) ? 1 : 0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. `POST my-index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.in_cr = 
        (ctx._source.indexable_bool == true && 
            (ctx._source.['csv_g-desktop'] > 0 || ctx._source.['csv_g-mobile'] > 0 )
        )
        ? 1 : 0"
    }
} .`   Bug report contains: `"type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "compile error",
    "script_stack": [
      "...  == true && (ctx._source.['csv_g-desktop'] ...",
      "                             ^---- HERE" .`

Comment: Oh I know why: in `ctx._source.['csv_g-mobile']` you need to remove the second dot, like this `ctx._source['csv_g-mobile']`

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry, I discover formatting with stackoverflow

Comment: Doesn't work ;( Just edited main question for full report

Comment: You have only replaced some occurrences but not all

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy and paste of bug report. Corrected

Comment: Can you go back to `ctx._source` and update the error please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173542/discussion-between-quentin-and-val).

Comment: Are you certain that all your documents have those fields, or can they be null in some documents?

Comment: They can be null documents / Not all documents have those fields

Comment: Ok then see my updated answer, we need to account for that in the query

Comment: Didn't know I had this super power ! Thanks :)